# 'data' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, destructor, goertzel-algorithm

I'm in the process of implementing the Goertzel Algorithm in C++, and I've gotten so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

const double pi = 3.14159;

class digitalFilter{
    private:
        int     k,i;
        float   temp;
        float   scalingFactor;
        float   floatnumSamples;
        float   omega,sine,cosine,coeff,q0,q1,q2,magnitude,real,imag;
        int const static limit = 205;
    public:
        digitalFilter();
        void readDataFromFile();
        float goertzel_mag(int numSamples,int TARGET_FREQUENCY,int SAMPLING_RATE, float* data);
};

digitalFilter::digitalFilter(){
    float* data = new float[limit];
}

void digitalFilter::readDataFromFile(){
    //get 205 values from txt file and store this in an array
    std::ifstream dataFile ("data_files/datad.txt");
    if (dataFile.is_open()){
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
            dataFile >> temp;
            data[i] = temp;
        }
        dataFile.close();
    }else{
        std::cout << "Unable to open file\n";
    }
}

float digitalFilter::goertzel_mag(int numSamples,int TARGET_FREQUENCY,int SAMPLING_RATE, float* data){
    scalingFactor = numSamples / 2.0;

    floatnumSamples = (float) numSamples;
    k = (int) (0.5 + ((floatnumSamples * TARGET_FREQUENCY) / SAMPLING_RATE));
    omega = (2.0 * pi * k) / floatnumSamples;
    sine = sin(omega);
    cosine = cos(omega);
    coeff = 2.0 * cosine;
    q0=0;
    q1=0;
    q2=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
    {
        q0 = coeff * q1 - q2 + data[i];
        q2 = q1;
        q1 = q0;
    }

    // calculate the real and imaginary results
    // scaling appropriately
    real = (q1 - q2 * cosine) / scalingFactor;
    imag = (q2 * sine) / scalingFactor;

    magnitude = sqrtf(real*real + imag*imag);
    std::cout << "a" << TARGET_FREQUENCY << " = " << magnitude << std::endl;
    return magnitude;
}


int main()
{
    digitalFilter ObjOne;
    //compute amplitude magnitude of DFT
    ObjOne.readDataFromFile();
    ObjOne.goertzel_mag(205,697,8000,data);
    ObjOne.goertzel_mag(205,770,8000,data);
    ObjOne.goertzel_mag(205,852,8000,data);
    ObjOne.goertzel_mag(205,941,8000,data);
    ObjOne.goertzel_mag(205,1209,8000,data);
    ObjOne.goertzel_mag(205,1336,8000,data);
    ObjOne.goertzel_mag(205,1477,8000,data);
    ObjOne.goertzel_mag(205,1633,8000,data);

    return 0;
}
```

But I get these silly error codes:

```
goertzel_mag-v3.cpp: In member function 'void digitalFilter::readDataFromFile()':
goertzel_mag-v3.cpp:41:4: error: 'data' was not declared in this scope
goertzel_mag-v3.cpp: In function 'int main()':
goertzel_mag-v3.cpp:85:35: error: 'data' was not declared in this scope
```

I am utterly and completely lost, why can't my member function `readDataFromFile()` find my array `data[]` ?? It seems like the constructor builds the array and then destroys it after the program leaves the constructor?? How can i fix these apparently silly errors?

Comment: Declare `float* data` along with other member variables, not in the constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by "my array"? A local variable you've declared in a different function?

Comment: Oh, sounds like you need to pick up C++ for beginners and try again :)

Comment: Kunal: I've just tried that, it works in all my member functions, but not in my main. I'd rather not declare it globally, what to do?

Comment: @NicolaiAntonLynnerup Did you try to access `data` in `main()` ?

Comment: @Kunal I've declared `data` under `public` now and tried to output the very first element of `data` like this: `std::cout << data[0];`. Still `data` is not in main's scope

Comment: @NicolaiAntonLynnerup Ok. Edit the question and show what you are doing now...

Comment: you should `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` and then use M_PI instead of declaring PI on your own like that. It has much more precision. Use PI with less precision like you did won't make the program faster

Comment: @NicolaiAntonLynnerup: I reverted your edit since it removes all relevant content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
digitalFilter::digitalFilter(){
    float* data = new float[limit];
}
```

After exiting the constructor function the `data` array ceases to exist. Make it a class member variable or a global one to retain it.

Comment: Yeah it works as a global one, but not as a class member variable as I'm using it in my main.

Comment: Well, whatever suits your needs - you can use it if it's a member variable in the main function by an accessor. Although you don't really need to pass it to member functions since they have direct access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing float *data as a member function will fix the first problem. 
as it is initialized in the constructor and will be available to only that block and goes out of scope

For the main part access it using the object once you make it a member function.
eg : obj.data

Comment: `float *data` is not a member function. Further, if it can can be accessed in `main()` depends on whether it is `public` or `private`

Comment: @Kunal exactly hence i asked him ti make it a data member, and public cause he's calling it again in main